# I'm trying to pick up new sentence structures

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

...and I came across this sentence: " It doesn't matter how good you are at identifying and fixing problems, if your written and spoken communication does not measure up, it will hold you back."

It has two independent clauses connected by one dependent clause. I'm trying to put this sentence into a category. Is this a compound sentence? ...a complex sentence? What kind of sentence is this?

Comment: Shouldn't the first comma be a semicolon?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, there are some structural problems.

I'd have written 'If your written and spoken communication doesn't measure up, it will hold you back—regardless of how good at identifying and solving problems you are.'

I find it helpful to break sentences down into simple terms ...

IF

Communication (subject)
doesn't measure up (verb - negative)

(THEN)

Communication [not measuring up] (subject)
will hold [back] (verb)
you (object)

REGARDLESS OF

how good (subject)
are (verb)
you (object)

('You' as the subject of the second part doesn't make sense).

So you have a compound complex subject (your written and spoken communication) and a complex predicate (doesn't measure up) in the first clause, a simple subject (it) and a complex predicate (will hold you back) in the second, and a complex subject (how good at identifying and solving problems) and a complex predicate (you are) in the third.

Alternatively, 'Your written and spoken communication not measuring up will hold you back, regardless of how good at identifying and solving problems you are.'

You've got me doubting myself as to whether this is a complex sentence or complex compound one, though. My money's on complex, but I'm open to improvements.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

> " What matters is not how good you are at identifying and fixing problems, but your written and spoken communication that will hold you back if does not measure up."

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?